# Чем можно заменить фразу "в значительном числе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

> Эти здания стали появляться у христиан в значительном числе лишь после
>   прекращения гонений со стороны язычников, то есть с четвёртого века.

Нам учительница говорила, что проверяющие ГИА не любят сочетание *большое количество*, т.к. «количество не может быть большим». Если это так, то чем тогда его заменить? Как тогда относиться к словосочетанию *в значительном числе*?

Comment: Цитирующий неправ и в том, что заменил цифровую запись буквенной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сами по себе обе фразы допустимы, а количество *бывает* большим или малым. Однако в историческом контексте они звучат излишне формально, "статистически", и с трудом представимо: что считать большим - сколько это на тысячу христиан и т. п.? Можно, конечно, обойти эти выражения словом "*массово*" (стали появляться)" или "*во множестве*", но такое впечатление, что "количество" или "число" вообще не несёт здесь полезной информации, а важнее то, что христиане там, где они появлялись, из-за гонений *не сразу и не везде* могли создавать себе храмы (в нужном им "количестве", которое нет смысла фразеологически оценивать, и нужного общине размера - по её численности). Поэтому лучше употребить другое слово:

> *Повсеместно* эти здания стали появляться у христиан лишь после прекращения гонений со стороны язычников, то есть с четвёртого века.

Answer (score 3):

Эта фраза является **цитатой**: *Храмы христианские, как особые богослужебные здания, стали появляться у христиан **в значительном числе** лишь после прекращения гонений со стороны язычников, то есть  с IV века.* https://www.pravmir.ru/hram-tserkov/

И количество может быть **большим, огромным, значительным** и т.д. Сочетаемость слова: [https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/количество](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Это **реальная оценка**, которая содержит вполне понятную для специалиста информацию.

**Проверяющие ГИА не любят фразу "большое количество"?** Надо бы с ними разобраться, да вот некому пока. Пусть хотя бы заглянут в Нацкорпус, там 930 примеров с этим сочетанием, вот один из них:

Хотя львы на воротах и стаи галок на крестах, а также аптеки, фонари, бульвары и прочее ещё имелись **в большом количестве**. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]